# Implicit expression for the ODE solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there is some implicit ODE solution like $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$. In fact, the ODE $y' = -\frac{x}{y}$ has multiple solutions (two): $y = \pm \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$, which are encoded by this implicit formula.

Is it possible that if the implicit formula represents some solutions to ODE, it also has some curves satisfying it, that are actually NOT a solution? For example, could the implicit formula above have some function $z$, such that $x^2 + z^2 = R^2$, but $z' \neq -\frac{x}{z}$?

More generally, is it possible, that $z$ satisfies some implicit expression $F(x, z, C_1) = 0$ for some constant $C_1$, while $F(x, z, C_2) \neq 0$, and at the same time there is a solution $y$ to some ODE, that $F(x, y, C_1) = 0, F(x, z, C_2) = 0$.

Comment: For your specific case, differentiating $x^2 + z^2 = R^2$ wrt x gives $2x + 2z(z') = 0 \implies z' = -\frac{x}{z}$, so you don't usually have that $z' = -\frac{x}{z}$, but with issues occurring as this is only true for $z \neq 0$, which is what leads to the $2$ different solutions. I don't know about the more general case, but perhaps implicit differentiation, like I did with your example, can answer the question.